# Is requiring captcha for API a design flaw?

Tags: api

And the reason is simple

It now asks for Captcha.

So I can access

https://c-cex.com/t/api_pub.html?a=getmarketsummaries on browser, do captca and I can accept that.

But my program cannot.

This is the code that failed

```
Public Shared Function downloadString1(url As String, post As String, otherHeaders As Tuple(Of String, String)()) As String
    Dim wc = New CookieAwareWebClient()

    For Each oh In otherHeaders
        wc.Headers.Add(oh.Item1, oh.Item2)
    Next

    Dim response = String.Empty
    For i = 1 To 1
        Try
            If post = "" Then
                response = wc.DownloadString(url)
            Else
                If post.Contains("=") Then
                    wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                End If
                response = wc.UploadString(url, post)

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim a = 1
        End Try
        If response = "" Then
            Sleep(1000)
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return response
End Function
```

And API should be used as program.

Is there a work around?

Or should I just complain to c-cex support about their API.

Is this a design flaw?

Note: Let me show you screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An API can't really ask for a CAPCHA as that's a mechanism to challenge that a user is human.  By definition almost, an API will not be.  If you need any challenge it would be authentication and authorisation which is typically done with a key, client cert or username/password.

If that URL is indeed designed as an API then I agree it's a design flaw. It didn't actually ask me for a capcha though when I used it.

Comment: It asks for captcha once and after that uses cookies.